# Finding the highest two values in each group

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find top 2 earners in each department

table => staff_masters 
having "staff_name" column for staffs and "dept_code" for corresponding department.

I tried to like this

```
SELECT TOP 2 staff_sal 
FROM staff_masters
GROUP BY dept_code;
```

Please use group by clause.

Comment: I want to use group by clause. is there any way to do that?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is for [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).  You, however, ask for [ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking).

Comment: hint for this task was  "use GROUP BY clause". So how can I do that using that ?

Comment: HINT: **Learn** SQL.  Your code is not Oracle and would not do what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select sm.*
from (select dept_code, staff_sal,
             row_number() over (partition by dept_code order by staff_sal desc) as seqnum
      from staff_masters
     ) sm
where seqnum <= 2;
```

If you want *distinct* salaries, you would use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Comment: hint for this task was  "use GROUP BY clause". So how can I do that using that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `Row_Number()` windowed function:

```
Select  Dept_Code, Staff_Sal
From
(
    Select  Dept_Code, Staff_Sal, 
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Dept_Code Order By Staff_Sal Desc) As RN
    From    Staff_Masters
) A
Where   RN <= 2
Order By Dept_Code, RN
```

Comment: hint for this task was  "use GROUP BY clause". So how can I do that using that ?

Comment: @ShyamSundar That's not what `GROUP BY` is designed for... `GROUP BY` is for *aggregation*... `ROW_NUMBER` is for ranking.  You are not trying to perform aggregation, you are trying to perform ranking, so you need to use `ROW_NUMBER`.  You are not going to be able to get that with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ok then thanks for the e